# Hard to find counterexample for $\partial (\partial A) = \partial A$

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

In an exercise I've proven that $\partial(\partial A) \subset \partial A$, for any $A\subset X$, where $X$ is a topological space and $\partial$ in this case stands for the boundary. Apparently, in general the equality does not hold, but I'm stumped when it comes to thinking of a counterexample. My problem is that for all of the spaces and sets I think of, the boundary always ends up being closed and with empty interior, so when taking the boundary a second time, I end up with the same.

Could someone come up with such an example please? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint.** Consider $(0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ in $\Bbb{R}$ with usual topology.

Comment: Thank you this works! Although the fact that $\overline{{\mathbb Q}\cap (0,1)} = (0,1)$ seemed obvious at first, it takes some mild justification.

Comment: @GPerez $\overline{\Bbb{Q}\cap(0,1)}$ is $[0,1]$, not $(0,1)$.

Comment: You can easily check that $\partial(\Bbb{Q}\cap(0,1))=[0,1]$ and $\partial[0,1]=\{0,1\}$.

Comment: oops sorry meant that